# Asyncio in Mako

Tags: python, templates, asynchronous, python-asyncio, mako

I really want to love Mako as I need a powerful template engine, which Mako is. However, no support for calling awaitables and async generators is really hurting my brain. I tried searching for workaround but have yet to find any.

Of course I could probably render the template in a separate thread, and wrap awaitables but nobody wants to do something like that.

Is there any better way/workaround?